# Unusual errors with xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, error

I am getting the following messages when running `xcodebuild` from the command line:

```
xcodebuild[22187:279813] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

```
xcodebuild[22187:279813] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

I am running MacOS Monterey (12.3) on an Intel iMac. I have reinstalled Xcode, as well as downgrading from 13 to 12.3.1, and the behavior has not changed. Unfortunately, I can't do much more to troubleshoot at the moment, as I have no idea what any part of these messages means, and Googling has not been much help.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore it (if you can). It's some kind of warning emitted by Xcode and there's not much you can do about it, short of installing the command-line tools and repointing `xcode-select` as suggest at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703233.